# How to reload twitter button?

Tags: ajax, button, twitter, render, reload

For ajax pages I call:

> twttr.widgets.load()

but never happens, it doesn't reload twitter button.

I tried also with

> twttr.widgets.load("nameDiv")

but I get this error:

TypeError: Object nameDiv has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

I solved with this solution (jQuery):

```
function reload_twitter_button() {
  $('.social-tw').html('');
  $('.social-tw').html('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="' + window.location.href + '">Tweet</a>');
  // refresh the widgets
  twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

Comment: I bow for you! Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, the page wasn't loaded before the load call was made. Wait for document ready to fire with:

```
$(function () {
    function loadWidgets(){
       twttr.widgets.load();
    }

    loadWidgets();
});
```

Comment: I think you meant twttr